# How to Solve two linear equations with two variables in java..?

Tags: java, apache, math, geometry, linear-equation

I have following equations:

```
  center_y -y1 = m * ( center_x - x1 );

  start_y - y1 = m * ( start_x - x1 );
```

where values of `center_y,center_x,start_y,start_x` and `m` are known and i want to get values of `x1` and `y1`...

Kindly provide an appropriate solution in java.../

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: m is a method.  What do you mean "it is known".  Please show the method because as it is, this question cannot be answered since each equation has 2 unknown variables and an unknown function.

Comment: @Simon Those are mathematical equations, not java assignment statements.

Comment: @simon m is a variable with a known value..or its like m*(center_x - x1).and similarly m*(start_x-x1)... Kindly tell me if it could be solved with apche maths library../

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming these are equations (i.e. m is a scalar, not a method), you can first rearrange the equations to get to a usual 2 variables / 2 equations model:

```
m.x1 - y1 = m.center_x - center_y
m.x1 - y1 = m.start_x - start_y
```

Then solve the linear system using [general techniques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations). And you will find out that because the 2 equations are colinear, there is either no solution or many solutions to that system...